# How to set placeholder text on top of input field? Bootstrap 4

Tags: angular

[The position of the text where I would like it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FspEA.png)I am using Bootstrap 4 and Angular 2. I have a large input field for text input. It is used for writing messages. My placeholder contains text "New text message". But the text is displayed in the middle of the text box and when the client starts filling the field with text a lot of blank space is on top. I would like him to be able to start typing on top. I am quite new to Bootsrap 4. Examples like class="text-left" are not working.

Text box with text in the middle:
[image: [Text box with text in the middle]]
[The position of the text where I would like it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FspEA.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read this before [**asking help**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: beside @Aravind advise (that you should consider), why your input are so large ? why not use `<textarea></textarea>` instead ?

Comment: Hy, I have to use <input type="text"></input> with name, id, placeholder, class, [(ngModel)] and required. Also with #partOfNgModel.

Comment: It is a part of a form-field control that we use on our project and I have to use it like that.